# Spring Boot 1.4: Executing Method after Liquibase finished

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a Spring Boot 1.4.0 based Project that uses Liquibase.

Is it possible to execute a Method AFTER liquibase finished?

Something like Bean Post Processor?

What i want to do is adding some data to my database when the application is started in development mode. In developement mode the application uses an in-memory h2 database, so liquibase has to create the tables before i can write my data.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Spring Boot auto-configures a `SpringLiquibase` bean named `liquibase`. Any bean that depends on this bean will be created after Liquibase has finished. For example, you could use `@PostConstruct` to populate the database:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("liquibase")
public YourBean yourBean() {
    return new YourBean();
}

static class YourBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void populateDatabase() {
        System.out.println("This will be called after Liquibase has finished");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Beautiful solution

Comment: sorry for commenting on old question.
What if `YourBean` and `liquibase` are on different threads ?
I have the same use case and this solution does not work for me. Any idea ?

Comment: Application context refresh is single-threaded. How are you getting into a situation where the two beans are being initialized in parallel?

Comment: I am using jhipster.
`liquibase` bean is initialized in other thread.
https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster/blob/master/jhipster-framework/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/config/liquibase/AsyncSpringLiquibase.java

Comment: As the javadoc of the class you've linked to says, you'll need to use the standard `SpringLiquibase` if you want to make database requests at startup.

Comment: I am facing an issue in multi-tenant application, when I create a database and run liquibase on it, the application restarts I don't know why. Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to let LiquiBase insert these things into your database - but only when running in dev-mode.

You can do this in LiquiBase by specifying a `context=""` attribute.

Another option would be to let LiquiBase only insert this test-data into your database when `dbms="h2db"` (forgot what the exact string is to select h2, check documentation please!)

Both are attributes on changesets.

This is my own preferred solution for this kind of scenarios.