# Spring Boot: run liquibase migrations without starting app

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

In Spring Boot, [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-liquibase-database-migrations-on-startup) seems to encourage running migrations on app startup.

This is fine, but sometimes app startup may have side effects / dependencies that I don't want to bother with - I just want to run the migrations on their own. Think just setting up a local dev database, to poke around in it, without even running the app.

In Dropwizard by comparison, running migrations alone [is straightforward](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.1/docs/manual/migrations.html#migrating-your-schema) with built in arguments for the app, like so

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db migrate helloworld.yml
```

Is there anything equivalent for Spring Boot? Or do I just have to drop down and run liquibase directly?

I'm interested in a direct answer, but also kind of interested in seeing if I'm misunderstanding something at a higher level - like perhaps this approach of running on startup is generally 'better' for some reasons I haven't discovered yet, so you're encouraged solely to do it this way by Spring Boot as a design choice.

Comment: have you tried to run the specific liquibase maven goal `liquibase:update`? http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_update.html

Comment: Can you disable it by configuration ? :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491234/configure-datasource-for-liquibase-in-spring-boot

Comment: We want to do this in a CI/CD pipeline _before_ our container gets deployed. Otherwise, if Liquibase runs at app startup, it will run with every auto-scaling event which is pointless. I take it you haven't found a solution?

Comment: @DarthPablo no, never found a solution. Unless switching back to Dropwizard counts ;-) And indeed, good point, just as you might not want side effects from running the app when you just want to run migrations, it's true vice versa too. Interesting design choice, never did find any convincing argument that it's a better way or had other benefits I wasn't aware of - I guess it's really just the obvious one that it's convenient you can never accidentally start the app without having run the latest migrations, but I am not sure that slight pro makes up for the cons here.

Comment: "Otherwise, if Liquibase runs at app startup, it will run with every auto-scaling event which is pointless" @DarthPablo when there are no migrations to apply, Liquibase only takes half a second to compare the list of migrations applied in the database with your migration files - it has never been an issue for us.  And if you start 2 instances of your application at the same time, they will not interfere with each other because Liquibase uses a database lock to make sure only one instance is processing the migrations at a time.

Comment: @Michael, I take your point, but we did actually have issues with slow starting applications and poor health check configuration with containers running on EC2 backed ECS clusters in AWS (when I believe containers can sometimes "steal" CPU from each other). A slow starting container would get the Liquibase lock and then ECS would sometimes terminate it for taking too long to start leaving the lock in place, preventing any other containers from starting, taking the service out until the lock was manually cleared. As I say though, this was down to poor configuration, but can happen.

Comment: @DarthPablo actually that has happened to us too, especially when doing an alter table command on a large and busy table, where the migration isn't able to complete in time, gets killed by Kubernetes and then the lock remains on the liquibase table and has to be cleared out manually...  So I see your point.  We had to increase the Kubernetes liveness probe timeouts, and still sometimes run into this.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone else stumbles upon it, this might be useful.

You can define a command line argument for your app, that you will use to only spin up a portion of the app context that will run migration.

Here's an example in Kotlin:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationContextFactory.ofContextClass
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import

@SpringBootApplication
class Application

@Import(DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class, LiquibaseAutoConfiguration::class)
class LiquibaseInit

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    if (args.contains("dbinit")) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder(LiquibaseInit::class.java)
            .contextFactory(ofContextClass(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext::class.java))
            .run(*args)
        return
    }

    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

Note: with Spring Boot 2.4.0 and earlier use `SpringApplicationBuilder#contextClass` instead of `contextFactory`.

We have 2 classes declared here: `Application` (the main app class having `@SpringBootApplication` annotation) and `LiquiBaseInit` (having `@DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and `@LiquibaseAutoConfiguration`), the first one will spin up the whole context, while the latter will only spin up the beans necessary for Liquibase to run migration.

Inside the main function we check if the arguments array has a string `dbinit` and if it is there we start an application context out of `LiquiBaseInit` class.

Now you can run migration with your jar file like this:

```sh
java -jar hello-world.jar dbinit
```

If you're going to run your app in Kubernetes, you might also want to check out this article in my blog: https://blog.monosoul.dev/2021/12/26/using-liquibase-with-kubernetes/ .

Answer (score 5):

You can use different Spring profiles: For instance, use a profile called 'init' which will activate the 'liquibase' profile.

application.yml: (disable Liquibase by default)

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: false
```

application-init.yml: (does not run a web container, so spring will close automatically after startup)

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: liquibase
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

spring-liquibase.yml: (enables liquibase)

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/changelog.xml
```

This setup allows you to run Liquibase as an init container (spring.profiles.active=init), but if you want to you can still run Liquibase as part of your web-app (spring.profiles.active=liquibase).

Comment: "does not run a web container, so spring will close automatically after startup": unfortunately, that's not the case - the app continues to run. `web-application-type` property only says not to start a web server, but the spring context is still loaded and doesn't want to shut down (tested on Spring Boot 3.1.4, not sure about other versions of Boot though).

Comment: @fightlight this usually means you have some user-thread that is still running. If you create a threaddump of the JVM after a minute, you should be able to see which thread prevents the automatic shutdown

Comment: yeah, I agree: if your app has only a web server and nothing more your solution works (and it might be the solution davnicwil asked about). But it's not a generic solution: the app could contain job worker threads, Kafka consumers, etc (which is my case) and it's impossible to achieve that only by configuration. My idea was to use the same app docker image for db migrations (as an initContainer) and for the app itself with different configuration: liquibase only, app only, both. Anyway, thanks for reply!

Comment: In a typical springboot app, the main thread is a user-thread, and any worker threads, kafka consumers etc are marked as 'daemon' threads. When the main thread exits, all other threads should be daemon. In our setup we use different Spring profiles: 'init' for running Liquibase schema migration, and 'web' for the Spring Boot app. This way you can configure which Configurations to enable. For local development you can activate both profiles.

Comment: Just went to start.spring.io and started a simple Spring web app with `@Scheduled` method and `spring.main.web-application-type=none` - the app continued to work. So it's not the case. And besides there could be hand started non-daemon threads, so your solution not a generic one. Sorry man.

Comment: You can disable specific beans which you do not want during init containers with `@Profile("web")` or `@Profile("!liquibase")`. Regarding the Scheduled threadpool: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17992 . All you need to do is call `close()` on the Spring app context: `SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args).close();` If you do not call `close()`, the threads in the Threadpool keep on running, since they are marked as user-threads. Bear in mind though that some 3rd party libraries might create user-threads, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38827016/4361713) mentions a hook that runs after Liquibase. In that question, it was used to populate the database, probably with test or default values.

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("liquibase")
public YourBean yourBean() {
    return new YourBean();
}

static class YourBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void shutdown() {
         // Exit your application here.
         );
    }

}
```

That could work. I don't know, you'd probably even have access to the liquibase mode and only shut down when it was "create."

Answer (score 0):

In general, it might be just less work to run migrations on app start, especially if you're using Spring Boot and its all set up for you.  You can then just stop the app.

However if you really would like to run migrations without the Spring Boot app, you can use the Liquibase Gradle and Maven plugins:
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin
https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/home.html

This will require you to set up the database credentials in another config file, in addition to your application config, so that the plugins can connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose we created our own script that allows not only to gen migrations but also to manually apply them, however it could be applied only from gradle, see:
https://github.com/Wissance/SpringUu

to apply update we use following command:

```
.\gradlew.bat update -PrunList='changesApply'
```

to specify db connection edit gradle section changesApply

For more details about our tool see article:

https://m-ushakov.medium.com/code-first-with-spring-boot-hibernate-and-liquibase-48f5c9998d95

Answer (score 0):

U can set up and configure maven liquibase plugin:
https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/home.html

It allows to use migrations without starting spring boot app itself

can be set up as part of building artifact or like separate task